# How to extend the creep class in screeps

Tags: javascript, screeps

I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to extend the creep class to add my own functions in the new javascript mmo game, Screeps  ->  [www.screeps.com](http://www.screeps.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dunno how to do that, but I created a wrapper class like this one:

You created a function for calling memory, and try to use it s property. See below:
var _ = require("lodash");

```
function MyCreep(creep){
    this.creep = creep;
    this.memoryProp = creep.memory;
}

MyCreep.prototype.memoryFunc = function(){
    return this.creep.memory;
};

MyCreep.prototype.moveTo = function(target){
    this.creep.moveTo(target);
}

MyCreep.prototype.myFunction = function(target){
    //TODO something
}
```

So when I need to deal with creep, I do:

```
var myCreeps = [];
for (var creep in Game.creeps){
    creep.memory.role = "hello memory";
    var myCreep = new MyCreep(Game.creeps[creep]);
    myCreeps.push(myCreep);      ;
    console.log("original creep memory: "+creep.memory.role);
    console.log("my creep memory func: "+myCreep.memoryFunc().role);
    console.log("my creep memory prop: "+myCreep.memoryProp.role);
}
```

or

```
var myCreeps = [];
_.forEach(Game.creeps, function(creep){
    var myCreep = new MyCreep(creep);
    myCreeps.push(myCreep);
});
```

and then deal with myCreeps, locally stored.

Comment: Pretty sure you should be doing `new MyCreep(Game.creeps[creep]);`

Comment: Oh yes, you.re right. Originally, I use lodash _.forEach(), which returns not the creep name, but th creep object itself. I updated my answer.

Comment: How do I handle basic creep functions after this?  For example mycreep.memory.role is now invalid.  I even tried to create a My Creep.prototype.memory = function() { return this.creep.memory }  but it was never called

Answer (score 7):

A bit of an old thread, and I am not sure if Screeps has changed since the initial query was posted, but here are my thoughts...

Why have a wrapper class?? why not extend the original / game provided Creep class ?

e.g.

```js
Creep.prototype.myFunction = function(target){
         // my logic
       }
```

Make sure to check out the screeps inheritance structure.. (Google the screeps API and  check out the 'Prototypes' section on the landing page)

This can save a lot of duplicate code, for example one declaration of an inherited function in the 'Structure' prototype may save a seperate declaration for each individual Structure sub class protocols.

Comment: You can also add properties using Object.defineProperty